# android delphi TWebBrowser behaviour on ScrollBox

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am trying to put a `TWebBrowser` inside `TPanel` which is inside a scroll box,
but when it run on devices while the other component on another panel in the same scroll box are work well, but the webbrowser don't get scrolled

The question is it the properties or something?

I've tried to change either align and anchor, but it won't works

Comment: Is another component `TWebBrowser` too?